# systemd service daemon and /dev/shm

Tags: linux, semaphore, daemon, systemd

I have a systemd service file that starts an application developed in C++ which creates a semaphore using

```
access_sem = sem_open("/sync_nvme_access_sem", O_CREAT, 0666);
if (access_sem == SEM_FAILED) {
       std::cerr << "Cannot create the semaphore" << std::endl;
       return false;
}
```

This is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=This is used to start the server
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/server
ExecStop=/bin/sh /usr/bin/stop-server.sh
WorkingDirectory=/
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The whole code is running nicely if I use the application alone (as root). But I cannot create the semaphore when the code runs from the daemon.

Why?

Comment: Print the error message with `perror("Cannot create the semaphore")` or add `strerror(errno)` to get more information.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Folowing the suggestion of @Boto, I put some more debug messages on the call of opening/creating the semaphore. I realized that a default argument was not used (I do not know why??) in the daemon versus the normal run of the code.

Therefore, sorry @Rob, but the problem was not the configuration of the systemd service unit but the code itself. The correct line of code is:

```
access_sem = sem_open("/sync_nvme_access_sem", O_CREAT, 0666, 1);
if (access_sem == SEM_FAILED) {
       std::cerr << "Cannot create the semaphore" << std::endl;
       return false;
}
```